# ASP.NET MVC SQL Command Error

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc

This is my code

```
        public static bool Login (string iduser, string password)
    {
        bool auth = false;
        string query = string.Format("Select * from [user] where iduser = '{0}' AND password = '{1}' ;", iduser, password);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        auth = re.HasRows;
        con.Close();
        return auth;

    }
```

When I execute my program an error appears on this line "SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();". The error message is: **Invalid password colonne**

Comment: Is that a real password that you've pasted? You might not want to broadcast a real password on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory. Your password coming from your `con` object is invalid. I would double check where that is being populated and make sure it is correct, since it appears to be a global variable.

Comment: Yep, on top of that, the code sample given couldn't be the real one since there isn't even a connection class given. :(

Comment: @Jetti Not necessarily, it could be a global connection variable

Comment: So much fun! password="blah'; drop table users --"